# How to program the revenue column in SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to create a SQL query that basically mimics the picture above. I have `date` and `profit` made on the month. I have to keep track of profit using revenue column and then find the profit made between `feb` and `mar`.

[image: Excel sample picture]

This is my code:

```
SELECT 
   pickup_datetime, 
   total_amount, 
   SUM(total_amount) OVER (order by pickup_datetime) AS Revenue 
FROM bigquery-public-data.new_york_taxi_trips.tlc_yellow_trips_2018
```

Answer (score 2):

Gordon is quite correct that you want to use a cumulative sum. Similarly commenters have made suggestions around subqueries but they require limit clauses.

The reason you are having issues with the taxi public dataset is that the data is keyed at a timestamp level which leaves a huge amount of unique data to run cumulative sums on. By casting to date within the Subquery you will get around this.

```
SELECT
  pickup_datetime AS Date,
  total_amount,
  SUM(total_amount) OVER (ORDER BY pickup_datetime) AS Revenue
FROM (
  SELECT
    DATE(pickup_datetime) AS pickup_datetime,
    sum(total_amount) AS total_amount
  FROM
    `bigquery-public-data.new_york_taxi_trips.tlc_yellow_trips_2018`
  GROUP BY 1)
ORDER BY 1
```

No runtime issues here: `Query complete (4.7 sec elapsed, 2.5 GB processed)`.

Let me know if you have any further questions.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want a cumulative sum.  Assuming you have a real date column:

```
select month, profit,
       sum(profit) over (order by month) as revenue
from t;
```

Comment: I tried that. Im getting this error : Resources exceeded during query execution: The query could not be executed in the allotted memory. Peak usage: 191% of limit. Top memory consumer(s): sort operations used for analytic OVER() clauses: 98% other/unattributed: 2%

Comment: This is my code: SELECT 
 pickup_datetime,
 total_amount,
 SUM(total_amount) OVER (order by  pickup_datetime) 
    AS  Revenue
 
FROM 
`bigquery-public-data.new_york_taxi_trips.tlc_yellow_trips_2018`;

Comment: The table is too large (112,234,626 rows) for such operation. Consider limiting the number of rows.

SELECT pickup_datetime, total_amount, SUM(total_amount) OVER (order by pickup_datetime) AS Revenue FROM (select * from `bigquery-public-data.new_york_taxi_trips.tlc_yellow_trips_2018` limit 100)

Comment: My bad, do not use 'select *'

SELECT pickup_datetime, total_amount, SUM(total_amount) OVER (order by pickup_datetime) AS Revenue FROM (select pickup_datetime, total_amount from `bigquery-public-data.new_york_taxi_trips.tlc_yellow_trips_2018` limit 100)

Comment: If you cast `pickup_datetime` to a date in your SubQuery this will run fine and you will not need the limit clause. The reason it fails is because it is trying to do cumulative sums on timestamps which will be very resource intensive.

Comment: @BilalAyash . . . This answers the question that you asked and it will not get a resource error on your sample data.  I see no use for having a cumulative sum over all the taxi data.  Perhaps you should ask another question that provides more information on what you really want to do.